# How to retrieve full shared Url within Android Application

Tags: android, intentfilter

My current Android Application has the following Intent Filter to accept shared web url's

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
</intent-filter>
```

The application works as expected apart from the fact that the URL my application receives from

```
final String htmlUriStr = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

is missing the last path parameters

e.g. if I share this web page

```
https://news.vanderbilt.edu/subscribe/available-feeds/page/2/
```

My application receives

```
https://news.vanderbilt.edu/subscribe/available-feeds/
```

Is there anything I can do to receive the complete URL?

**UPDATE**

The above issue was when I use Chrome to browse to the target page.

When I use Firefox or FireFox beta my application receives the complete URL.

Seems to be a Chrome "feature".

Ive tested numerous browsers and they all share the complete url, seems to be a failing in Chrome only.

Comment: Try to get from EXTRA_STREAM instead of EXTRA_TEXT

Comment: @VishalChhodwani doesn't that just give me a screen shot of the web page? android.intent.extra.SUBJECT Available RSS Feeds | Vanderbilt News | Vanderbilt University (java.lang.String)
android.intent.extra.TEXT https://news.vanderbilt.edu/subscribe/available-feeds/ (java.lang.String)
org.chromium.chrome.extra.TASK_ID 119 (java.lang.Integer)
share_screenshot_as_stream content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/BlockedFile_13410905732696 (android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri)